# WordPress New Theme adding Error

Tags: php, wordpress, wamp

I am trying to install a new theme. After copying it to the themes folder and entering the themes admin panel to activate the theme I get 3 warning error:

Warning: fopen(C:\wamp\www\wordpress/wp-content/themes/idealdevelopments/style.css) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\wamp\www\wordpress\wp-includes\functions.php on line 4782

Warning: fread() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\wordpress\wp-includes\functions.php on line 4785

Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\wordpress\wp-includes\functions.php on line 4788

Answer (score 1):

Change your folder permissions.

Comment: i add full permission to that folder...but the error coming again , thats the problem